# Returning a count of found_rows along with a limited active records query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

Please excuse the noobee nature of this question.

I have a Story model.  Each story has a category attribute stored in its own DB column.  I have a named scope called :in_categories, which returns all of the stories that have a category that is included in a given category array:

```
  scope :in_categories, lambda {|categories|
        where(:category => categories)
  }
```

What I now want to do is limit the length of the response, but also return a count of the total number of respondent rows in the DB, ignoring the limit.  For instance, say I changed the scope to be:

```
  scope :in_categories, lambda {|categories|
        where(:category => categories).limit(20)
  }
```

but there are actually 35 stories that have a category in the categories array.  How can I get back the 20 active records objects and a count variable of 35?  Do I need to have a second DB query?  I've come across the FOUND_ROWS_ function in mysql, but I'm using postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1185863074.10580.91.camel@linda.lfix.co.uk

> There is no equivalent.  Use
>
> ```
> BEGIN;
> SELECT * FROM mytable OFFSET X LIMIT Y;
> SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM mytable;
> END;
> ```
>
> (To ensure consistent results, both queries should be done in a single
>   transaction.)

don't have rails env on hand therefore only pseudocode

```
Story.transaction do
  story.in_categories
  story.where(:category => categories).count
end
```

more info about active record transactions http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Actually we don't use transactions and simply execute these queries sequentially. Never had problems with that but of course it depends on your project.

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  But, how would I create these queries inside of a rails controller so that I could access both responses while still ensuring consistent results?

Comment: I would really like to accept your answer, but my original question asks for how to do this within the context of active_records.  I don't understand how to do both queries inside a single AR transaction or if it's even possible.  Can you expand?

Comment: Updated my answer. if you have more questions feel free to ping me.